# Adding column in attribute table with values sampled from raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table, sample

I am working with QGIS. I have a file with many points, and I would like to sample their values from a raster.

How can I add a column in the points' attribute table and fill it with the raster values?

Comment: Processing Toolbox, search for *Sample raster values*, et voilà?

Answer (score 3):

Use the "Sample Raster Values" QGIS Processing Algorithm.

The help for the tool states:

> **Sample raster values**
>
> This algorithm creates a new vector layer with
>   the same attributes of the input layer and the raster values
>   corresponding on the point location.
>
> If the raster layer has more than
>   one band, all the band values are sampled.

Preview of the tool:
[image]

General usage of the tool:
Select your Input Point Layer (if not auto-selected)
Select your Raster layer (Local rasters only, can not be a WMS/WMTS/XYZTile/etc.)
(Optional) Rename your Raster Attribute Column(s) with a prefix

Comment: Is there a process that will work for rasters from ArcGIS MapServer data sources?